# problem in cell.accessoryType in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

In my app if user press on any cell in UITableView then accessoryType of cell will be set to check mark like following

```
-(void)Check:(UITableView *)tableView Mark:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;  
     buttonCount++;  
    [selectedCellArray addObject:indexPath];  
}
```

and if user press the same cell then uncheck will happen as follows

```
-(void)UnCheck:(UITableView *)tableView Mark:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{  
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType =   UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;  
    buttonCount--;    
     if (buttonCount == 0) {    

        [selectedCellArray removeAllObjects];  
    }  
}
```

and i am calling this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
if([tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
    {  
        [self UnCheck:tableView Mark:indexPath];  
    }  
else  
    {  
        [self Check:tableView Mark:indexPath];

    }
```

Problem is when i am pressing on 1st cell it call Check method and mark the cell to but when i am scroll down i find 2-3 more cheked cell ...even i did not select those cell...i dont know why and how it checked automatically ...
i hope some one know where is the problem
thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because cells will be reused by the tableview. Also set the checkmark/accessory type in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: perfect , thank you very much but now if i select 4-5 cells and scroll down or up i can not see the check marks

Comment: You'd have to set the type (in cellForRow...) depending on whether the indexPath is in selectedCellArray. You must understand that in cellForRow..., using dequeCell... you will sometimes create a whole new cell and sometimes reuse an existing one. So the cell needs to be reconfigured (accessory type set, etc.) each time you return a cell. Try skipping the dequeCell... to see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

ya.. I see this happen a lot.

the correct pattern to manage the UITableViewCell state is NOT to directly manipulate the TableViewCell to update the UI, and always set, draw and create the correct state from cellForRowAtIndexPath (or tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)

Meaning, if the user clicks on the cell and you need to update the UI of that cell, store the new state of that cell in an array or dictionary (I find that an NSMutableDictionary with the NSIndexPath as the key works very well).

then call the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: or just [tableView reloadData] so that the cellForRowAtIndexPath reads that array or Dictionary and correctly draws the cell.

otherwise, the cellForRowAtIndexPath will constantly overwrite your changes and use recycled cells that hold incorrect state.

one exception to this rule would be if you would like a nice animation between the two states... if that is the case, save off your new state, perform your animation right there on the cell, then when the animation completes, call the same reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation or reloadData so that the cell is redrawn in its new state.

Comment: should i call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:mehtod

Comment: no.. that would cause a stack overflow.  reloadRowsAtIndexPaths causes the tableView to call cellForRowAtIndexPath